# Unable to update Remote Desktop using App Store

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore, software-update, apple-remote-desktop

Apple's Remote Desktop recently updated but I'm unable to install the update from the App Store, where I get the message:

> This update is not available for this Apple ID either because it was bought by a different user or the item was refunded or cancelled.

I purchased Remote Desktop before the App Store existed (or at least I think I purchased it through a different channel).

How do I update ARD if the App Store won't let me?

Answer (score 1):

Is it in your purchase history? I'm guessing no.

Apple changed the policy on ARD a while ago. It went from 'serial number' to App Store, & any existing ARD on the machine should have been 'upgraded' to that at the time. Mine was showing as purchased, but not available as an update.

The App Store app was showing it as 'Open' which it wouldn't because the client had already updated to 3.9, which sent me back to the App Store -  so I was locked in an infinite loop

My fix was to trash the app [or zip it & trash] then go to it in the App Store https://itunes.apple.com/app/id409907375 which then showed it as 'Install' & I was up & running.

Alternative approach I've heard to work was - remove ARD from Apps, launch App Store, check for the ARD app, which shows as to buy, quit App Store, put ARD back in Apps & check again.

A third possibility - untested & definitely worth having a backup - see if `com.apple.pkg.RemoteDesktopAdmin_AppStore` either `.bom` or `.plist` exist in `/private/var/db/receipts`. Trash & try one of the above methods.
I'm not certain whether this is double-checked in `/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist` hence the backup recommendation.

Comment: None of these methods work. Nor does any combination of them.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to ask Apple - whichever account made the original purchase, or conversion to App Store ownership.

Comment: Clearly. I'll report what I learn.